# Is it possible (plugin?) to use a camera input (solidview or materialview) in the compositor as a preview?

Tags: compositing-nodes

While in the compositor, the usual input is the renderlayer, but when compositing, mostly when checking masks or rotoscoping, having a simple preview instead of a final render as an input is quite good (and fast) enough, so, instead of having to press f12 every time I move to other part of an animation to check, is there a way to use a camera output instead of render layer as a kind-of proxy to speed up. Yes, I know you can render the viewport into a sequence or videofile and use a moviefile input, but being a workaround for a specific situation, it's doesn't answer the general question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using 2.8x, you can change the render engine to 'Workbench.'

[image: Render Properties -> Render Engine: change to 'Workbench']

It's the equivalent of a viewport render in previous Blender versions, except it ports into Blender's rendering system, and therefore the compositor.  It should render a frame about as quickly as the viewport, and gives you to extra options (depth of field, outline, basic shadows, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, that might speed it up a bit. Never the less, I still have to press F12 to update.  The "Auto Render" on the Options->Performance tab, just re-renders on updates or edits of the 3d scene, but not on timeline scrubbing. I guess it wouldn't be nice to forget to change the render settings and have to wait 3 minutes for the update. Nice one!

Comment: Yeah, until they add an input node for the scene, you'll just have to re-render for the compositor.  Another option for simple color grading or effects is the sequence editor!  You may be able to use mask, but I'd have to check that to confirm.